# Error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In my project I'm using a navigation drawer with tabs. In one of the tabs i want to call a google map but them i face this error:

`Error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to MapFragment`

**The Fragment which contains the map:**

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout,container,false);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //toDO 
    }
}
```

**The Tab Fragment**

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 3 ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
               }
    });

    return x;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
      switch (position){
          case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
          case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
          case 2 : return new UpdatesFragment();
      }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Primary";
            case 1 :
                return "Social";
            case 2 :
                return "Updates";
        }
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

**The Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
         mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;
         mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
         mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

         mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



             if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SentFragment()).commit();

             }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
            }

             return false;
        }

    });

            android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
}
```

**The xml of primary_fragment**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I'm importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` on the fragments and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` on the main activity.

Comment: try casting to SupportMapFragment

Comment: Which line in your code throws this error and can you paste your layout xml please ?

Comment: It's on the line `MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`

Comment: Itzik Samara comment solved my problem. Thx guys

Answer (score 4):

Using with SupportMapFragment solved on my side : (tnx @Itzzik Samara)

```
SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
```

instead of

```
MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a casting issue to me you are trying to cast to a MapFragment

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Comment: This is the line that throws the error. Any suggestion on how to fix it? The odd thing is that I've already used the same line without anny errors when using only navigation drawer without tabs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your **MainActivity.java**
2. Remove this line of code:
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
3. Now replace the **Point No 2 code** by this new code:
   MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
4. Now rebuild your project. You are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by  casting `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`as stated by Itzik Samara on the comments

Answer (score 0):

Use **SupportMapFragment** instead of **MapFragment** and refractor the project into androidx by going into Refractor menu and Click on **Migrate to AndroidX** in android studio in your project. It will work with any map sdk version.