# error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty73M.png)i want to add google map for my project. i am trying to do that then i have this problem

```
public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map3);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

> xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".DriverMapActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Show error logs

Comment: Show the stack trace. I think this is probably you are using map fragment in XML and Cast in code with SupportMapFragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900544/error-incompatible-types-fragment-cannot-be-converted-to-mapfragment)

Comment: @Ruwan - Please show your all code so that i can see which class you import for SupportMapFragment and also show the xml file code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. User MapView in place of Fragment

     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/provider_map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


 2. Update your gradle files as follows
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'    
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'    
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'    
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Step-1 - In your xml file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
```

Step - 2 - In your java file

Use this class **import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;**

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Log.d("tag", "onMapReady");
        }
    });
mapFragment.getMapAsync( this);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with that. Try to use a normal FrameLayout and the add the fragment by code.